# What is the Correct Method of Calling a Function of a New Contract?

Tags: web3js

what is the correct way to call a method of a contract that has recently been created.

following the example on the officially documentation (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract), i have successfully created and deployed a new contract instances with the following code:

```
import commentContract from '../build/contracts/Comment.json';

const comment = new web3.eth.Contract(Comment.abi, { from: coinbase });

comment.deploy({ data: commentContract.bytecode })
    .send({ from: coinbase, gas: 1500000 })
    .then(deployedContract => {
        // return deployedContract.methods.setText('some text here', {from: coinbase})
        //     .then(result => console.log(result))

        return deployedContract.methods.setText('some text here')
            .then(result => console.log(result))
    });
```

this code does not work because of an error that `setText` expects only 1 parameter, instead 2 supplied ( because of `{from: coinbase}`). so i removed the `{from: coinbase}` part from the code and now it gives an error that `then` is not defined.

so i cant figure out what the correct way would be to call methods on this newly created contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both case the syntax is wrong. If `setText` is going to change the status you need to send a transaction:

```
const tx = await deployedContract.methods.setText('some text').send({
  from: coinbase
});
console.log(tx)
// or
deployedContract.methods.setText('some text').send({
  from: coinbase
}).then(console.log);
```

if not you can just provide a call:

```
console.log(await deployedContract.methods.setText('some text').call())
// or
deployedContract.methods.setText('some text').call().then(console.log)
```